# Doing simple function on mongodb collection without storing it to memory?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have 1000 users in my mongo db collections, i want to do some updating on them without loading them into the memory, the updating are those:

In every user Object i have the following:

```
user : {
    money : 100,
    skill : 50,
    stamina : 50
}
```

I want to do the following simple operations:

```
 user.skill            = Math.max(0, user.skill + 50);
 user.stamina          = Math.max(0,Math.min(100, user.stamina + 20));
 user.moral              = Math.max(0,Math.min(100, user.moral + 10));
```

But again, an update like but not to store them in memory, is it even possible doing those kind of checks? (maybe more complicated things?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at update operators in Mongodb : 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/

Those operators are usefull to update fields in documents without loading the document to the client, so it looks appropriate to your case :)

You would need : [$inc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#up._S_inc), [$min](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/min/#up._S_min), [$max](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/max/#up._S_max),